# Combine lines with matching keys

Tags: python, linux, perl, awk

I have a text file with the following structure

```
ID,operator,a,b,c,d,true
WCBP12236,J1,75.7,80.6,65.9,83.2,82.1
WCBP12236,J2,76.3,79.6,61.7,81.9,82.1
WCBP12236,S1,77.2,81.5,69.4,84.1,82.1
WCBP12236,S2,68.0,68.0,53.2,68.5,82.1
WCBP12234,J1,63.7,67.7,72.2,71.6,75.3
WCBP12234,J2,68.6,68.4,41.4,68.9,75.3
WCBP12234,S1,81.8,82.7,67.0,87.5,75.3
WCBP12234,S2,66.6,67.9,53.0,70.7,75.3
WCBP12238,J1,78.6,79.0,56.2,82.1,84.1
WCBP12239,J2,66.6,72.9,79.5,76.6,82.1
WCBP12239,S1,86.6,87.8,23.0,23.0,82.1
WCBP12239,S2,86.0,86.9,62.3,89.7,82.1
WCBP12239,J1,70.9,71.3,66.0,73.7,82.1
WCBP12238,J2,75.1,75.2,54.3,76.4,84.1
WCBP12238,S1,65.9,66.0,40.2,66.5,84.1
WCBP12238,S2,72.7,73.2,52.6,73.9,84.1
```

Each `ID` corresponds to a dataset which is analysed by an operator several times. i.e `J1` and `J2` are the first and second attempt by operator J. The measures `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` use 4 slightly different algorithms to measure a value whose true value lies in the column `true`

What I would like to do is to create 3 new text files comparing the results for `J1` vs `J2`, `S1` vs `S2` and `J1` vs `S1`. Example output for `J1` vs `J2`:

```
ID,operator,a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2,d1,d2,true
WCBP12236,75.7,76.3,80.6,79.6,65.9,61.7,83.2,81.9,82.1
WCBP12234,63.7,68.6,67.7,68.4,72.2,41.4,71.6,68.9,75.3
```

where `a1` is measurement `a` for `J1`, etc.

Another example is for `S1` vs `S2`:

```
ID,operator,a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2,d1,d2,true
WCBP12236,77.2,68.0,81.5,68.0,69.4,53.2,84.1,68.5,82.1
WCBP12234,81.8,66.6,82.7,67.9,67.0,53,87.5,70.7,75.3
```

The IDs will not be in alphanumerical order nor will the operators be clustered for the same ID. I'm not certain how best to approach this task - using linux tools or a scripting language like perl/python.

My initial attempt using linux quickly hit a brick wall

First find all unique IDs (sorted)

```
awk -F, '/^WCBP/ {print $1}' file | uniq | sort -k 1.5n > unique_ids
```

Loop through these IDs and sort `J1`, `J2`:

```
foreach i (`more unique_ids`)
    grep $i test.txt | egrep 'J[1-2]' | sort -t',' -k2
end
```

This gives me the data sorted

```
WCBP12234,J1,63.7,67.7,72.2,71.6,75.3
WCBP12234,J2,68.6,68.4,41.4,68.9,80.4
WCBP12236,J1,75.7,80.6,65.9,83.2,82.1
WCBP12236,J2,76.3,79.6,61.7,81.9,82.1
WCBP12238,J1,78.6,79.0,56.2,82.1,82.1
WCBP12238,J2,75.1,75.2,54.3,76.4,82.1
WCBP12239,J1,70.9,71.3,66.0,73.7,75.3
WCBP12239,J2,66.6,72.9,79.5,76.6,75.3
```

I'm not sure how to rearrange this data to get the desired structure. I tried adding an additional pipe to `awk` in the `foreach` loop `awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n\n"} {print $1, $3,$10,$4,$11,$5,$12,$6,$13,$7}'`

Any ideas? I'm sure this can be done in a less cumbersome manner using `awk`, although it may be better using a proper scripting language.

Comment: In your second code block, did you intend for the `82.1` to appear only once? Sorry, re-read the question, noticed it is the 'true' value.

Comment: Also, why do you need J1 v J2 twice?

Comment: icedwater is referring to the part that says you want results for `J1 vs J2, S1 vs S2 and J1 vs J2`

Comment: Appologies for the typo. I meant `J1 vs J2`, `S1 vs S2` and `J1 vs S1`

Comment: How come in your file, the same dataset ID can have different `true` values? For example, `WCBP12234`

Comment: @doubleDown - They don't. I edited a few of the lines as I didn't have a complete data set J1,J2,S1,S2. I just wanted to communicate my problem and desired output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Perl csv module [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV) to extract the fields, and then store them in a hash, where ID is the main key, the second field is the secondary key and all the fields are stored as the value. It should then be trivial to do whatever comparisons you want. If you want to retain the original order of your lines, you can use an array inside the first loop.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my %data;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
            binary => 1,      # safety precaution
            eol    => $/,     # important when using $csv->print()
    });
while ( my $row = $csv->getline(*ARGV) ) {
    my ($id, $J) = @$row;   # first two fields
    $data{$id}{$J} = $row;  # store line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Python Way:

```
import os,sys, re, itertools
info=["WCBP12236,J1,75.7,80.6,65.9,83.2,82.1",
  "WCBP12236,J2,76.3,79.6,61.7,81.9,82.1",
  "WCBP12236,S1,77.2,81.5,69.4,84.1,82.1",
  "WCBP12236,S2,68.0,68.0,53.2,68.5,82.1",
  "WCBP12234,J1,63.7,67.7,72.2,71.6,75.3",
  "WCBP12234,J2,68.6,68.4,41.4,68.9,80.4",
  "WCBP12234,S1,81.8,82.7,67.0,87.5,75.3",
  "WCBP12234,S2,66.6,67.9,53.0,70.7,72.7",
  "WCBP12238,J1,78.6,79.0,56.2,82.1,82.1",
  "WCBP12239,J2,66.6,72.9,79.5,76.6,75.3",
  "WCBP12239,S1,86.6,87.8,23.0,23.0,82.1",
  "WCBP12239,S2,86.0,86.9,62.3,89.7,82.1",
  "WCBP12239,J1,70.9,71.3,66.0,73.7,75.3",
  "WCBP12238,J2,75.1,75.2,54.3,76.4,82.1",
  "WCBP12238,S1,65.9,66.0,40.2,66.5,80.4",
  "WCBP12238,S2,72.7,73.2,52.6,73.9,72.7" ]

def extract_data(operator_1, operator_2):
    operator_index=1
    id_index=0
    data={}
    result=[]
    ret=[]
    for line in info:
        conv_list=line.split(",")
        if len(conv_list) > operator_index and ((operator_1.strip().upper() == conv_list[operator_index].strip().upper()) or (operator_2.strip().upper() == conv_list[operator_index].strip().upper()) ):
            if data.has_key(conv_list[id_index]):
                iters = [iter(conv_list[int(operator_index)+1:]), iter(data[conv_list[id_index]])]
                data[conv_list[id_index]]=list(it.next() for it in itertools.cycle(iters))
                continue
            data[conv_list[id_index]]=conv_list[int(operator_index)+1:]
    return data

ret=extract_data("j1", "s2")
print ret
```

O/P:

> {'WCBP12239': ['70.9', '86.0', '71.3', '86.9', '66.0', '62.3', '73.7', '89.7', '75.3', '82.1'], 'WCBP12238': ['72.7', '78.6', '73.2', '79.0', '52.6', '56.2', '73.9', '82.1', '72.7', '82.1'], 'WCBP12234': ['66.6', '63.7', '67.9', '67.7', '53.0', '72.2', '70.7', '71.6', '72.7', '75.3'], 'WCBP12236': ['68.0', '75.7', '68.0', '80.6', '53.2', '65.9', '68.5', '83.2', '82.1', '82.1']}

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use Text::CSV like TLP did. If you needed to you could but for this example, I thought since there were no embedded commas in the fields, I did a simple split on ','. Also, the true fields from both operators are listed (instead of just 1) as I thought the special case of the last value complicates the solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw/ mesh /;

my %data;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($id, $op, @vals) = split /,/;
    $data{$id}{$op} = \@vals;
}

my @ops = ([qw/J1 J2/], [qw/S1 S2/], [qw/J1 S1/]);

for my $id (sort keys %data) {
    for my $comb (@ops) {
        open my $fh, ">>", "@$comb.txt" or die $!;
        my $a1 = $data{$id}{ $comb->[0] };
        my $a2 = $data{$id}{ $comb->[1] };
        print $fh join(",", $id, mesh(@$a1, @$a2)), "\n";
        close $fh or die $!;
    }   
}

__DATA__
WCBP12236,J1,75.7,80.6,65.9,83.2,82.1
WCBP12236,J2,76.3,79.6,61.7,81.9,82.1
WCBP12236,S1,77.2,81.5,69.4,84.1,82.1
WCBP12236,S2,68.0,68.0,53.2,68.5,82.1
WCBP12234,J1,63.7,67.7,72.2,71.6,75.3
WCBP12234,J2,68.6,68.4,41.4,68.9,75.3
WCBP12234,S1,81.8,82.7,67.0,87.5,75.3
WCBP12234,S2,66.6,67.9,53.0,70.7,75.3
WCBP12239,J1,78.6,79.0,56.2,82.1,82.1
WCBP12239,J2,66.6,72.9,79.5,76.6,82.1
WCBP12239,S1,86.6,87.8,23.0,23.0,82.1
WCBP12239,S2,86.0,86.9,62.3,89.7,82.1
WCBP12238,J1,70.9,71.3,66.0,73.7,84.1
WCBP12238,J2,75.1,75.2,54.3,76.4,84.1
WCBP12238,S1,65.9,66.0,40.2,66.5,84.1
WCBP12238,S2,72.7,73.2,52.6,73.9,84.1
```

The output files produced are below

J1 J2.txt

```
WCBP12234,63.7,68.6,67.7,68.4,72.2,41.4,71.6,68.9,75.3,75.3
WCBP12236,75.7,76.3,80.6,79.6,65.9,61.7,83.2,81.9,82.1,82.1
WCBP12238,70.9,75.1,71.3,75.2,66.0,54.3,73.7,76.4,84.1,84.1
WCBP12239,78.6,66.6,79.0,72.9,56.2,79.5,82.1,76.6,82.1,82.1
```

S1 S2.txt

```
WCBP12234,81.8,66.6,82.7,67.9,67.0,53.0,87.5,70.7,75.3,75.3
WCBP12236,77.2,68.0,81.5,68.0,69.4,53.2,84.1,68.5,82.1,82.1
WCBP12238,65.9,72.7,66.0,73.2,40.2,52.6,66.5,73.9,84.1,84.1
WCBP12239,86.6,86.0,87.8,86.9,23.0,62.3,23.0,89.7,82.1,82.1
```

J1 S1.txt

```
WCBP12234,63.7,81.8,67.7,82.7,72.2,67.0,71.6,87.5,75.3,75.3
WCBP12236,75.7,77.2,80.6,81.5,65.9,69.4,83.2,84.1,82.1,82.1
WCBP12238,70.9,65.9,71.3,66.0,66.0,40.2,73.7,66.5,84.1,84.1
WCBP12239,78.6,86.6,79.0,87.8,56.2,23.0,82.1,23.0,82.1,82.1
```

**Update:** To get only 1 true value, the for loop could be written like this:

```
for my $id (sort keys %data) {
    for my $comb (@ops) {
        local $" = '';
        open my $fh, ">>", "@$comb.txt" or die $!;
        my $a1 = $data{$id}{ $comb->[0] };
        my $a2 = $data{$id}{ $comb->[1] };
        pop @$a2;
        my @mesh = grep defined, mesh(@$a1, @$a2);
        print $fh join(",", $id, @mesh), "\n";
        close $fh or die $!;
    }   
}
```

Update: Added 'defined' for test in grep expr. as it is the proper way (instead of just testing '$_', which possibly could be 0 and wrongly excluded for the list by grep).

Answer (score 0):

Any problem that `awk` or `sed` can solve, there is no doubt that `python`, `perl`, `java`, `go`, `c++`, `c` can too. However, it is not necessary to write a complete program in any of them.

Use `awk` in one liner

**VERSION 1**

For the most use cases, I think the VERSION 1 is good enough.

```
tail -n +2 file |   # the call to `tail` to remove the 1st line is not necessary
sort -t, -k 1,1 |
awk -F ',+' -v OFS=, '$2==x{id=$1;a=$3;b=$4;c=$5;d=$6} id==$1 && $2==y{$3=a","$3; $4=b","$4; $5=c","$5; $6=d","$6; $2=""; $0=$0; $1=$1; print}' \
    x=J1 y=S1
```

Just replace the value of the argument `x` and `y` with what you like.

Please note the value of `x` and `y` must follow the alphabet order, e.g., `x=J1 y=S1` is OK, but `x=S1 y=J1` doesn't work.

**VERSION 2**

The limitation mentioned in VERSION 1 that you have to specify the `x` and `y` in alphabet order is removed. Like, `x=S1 y=J1` is OK now.

```
tail -n +2 file |   # the call to `tail` to remove the 1st line is not necessary
sort -t, -k 1,1 |
awk -F ',+' -v OFS=, 'id!=$1 && ($2==x||$2==y){z=$2==x?y:x; id=$1; a=$3;b=$4;c=$5;d=$6} id==$1 && $2==z{$3=a","$3;$4=b","$4;$5=c","$5;$6=d","$6; $2=""; $0=$0; $1=$1; print}' \
    x=S1 y=J1
```

However, the data of `J1` is still put before the data of `S1`, which means the column `a1` in the resulting output is always the column `a` of `J1` in the input file, and `a2` in the resulting output is always the column `a` of `S1` in the input file.

**VERSION 3**

The limitation mentioned in the VERSION 2 is removed. Now with `x=S1 y=J1`, the output column `a1` would be the input column `a` of `S1`, and the `a2` would be the `a` of `J1`.

```
tail -n +2 file |   # the call to `tail` to remove the 1st line is not necessary
sort -t, -k 1,1 |
awk -F ',+' -v OFS=, 'id!=$1 && ($2==x||$2==y){z=$2==x?y:x; id=$1; a=$3;b=$4;c=$5;d=$6} id==$1 && $2==z{if (z==y) {$3=a","$3;$4=b","$4;$5=c","$5;$6=d","$6} else {$3=$3","a;$4=$4","b;$5=$5","c;$6=$6","d} $2=""; $0=$0; $1=$1; print}' \
    x=S1 y=J1
```