# Combine lines with matching first field

Tags: unix, join, awk, command-line, bsd

For a few years, I often have a need to combine lines of (sorted) text with a matching first field, and I never found an elegant (i.e. one-liner unix command line) way to do it. What I want is similar to what's possible with the unix `join` command, but `join` expects 2 files, with each key appearing maximum once. I want to start with a single file, in which a key might appear multiple tiles.

I have both a ruby and perl script that do this, but there's no way to shorten my algorithm into a one-liner. After years of unix use, I'm still learning new tricks with `comm`, `paste`, `uniq`, etc, and I suspect there's a smart way to do this.

There are some related questions, like [join all lines that have the same first column to the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623035/join-all-lines-that-have-the-same-first-column-to-the-same-line?noredirect=1&lq=1); [Command line to match lines with matching first field (sed, awk, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493326/command-line-to-match-lines-with-matching-first-field-sed-awk-etc); and [Combine lines with matching keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272454/combine-lines-with-matching-keys) -- but those solutions never really give a clean and reliable solution.

Here's sample input:

```
apple:A fruit
apple:Type of: pie
banana:tropical fruit
cherry:small burgundy fruit
cherry:1 for me to eat
cherry:bright red
```

Here's sample output:

```
apple:A fruit;Type of: pie
banana:tropical fruit
cherry:small burgundy fruit;1 for me to eat;bright red
```

Here's my ideal syntax:

```
merge --inputDelimiter=":" --outputDelimiter=";" --matchfield=1 infile.txt
```

The "matchfield" is really optional. It could always be the first field. Subsequent appearances of the delimiter should be treated like plain text.

I don't mind a perl, ruby, awk one-liner, if you can think of a short and elegant algorithm. This should be able to handle millions of lines of input. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Using **awk** one liner

```
awk -F: -v ORS="" 'a!=$1{a=$1; $0=RS $0} a==$1{ sub($1":",";") } 1' file
```

**Output:**

```
apple:A fruit;Type of: pie
banana:tropical fruit
cherry:small burgundy fruit;1 for me to eat;bright red
```

setting `ORS=""` ; By default it is  `\n`.
The reason why we have set `ORS=""` (Output Record Separator) is because we don't want awk to include newlines in the output at the end of each record. We want to handle it in our own way, through our own logic. We are actually including newlines at the start of every record which has the first field different from the previous one.

`a!=$1` : When variable `a` (initially null) doesn't match with first field `$1` which is for eg. `apple`in first line, then set `a=$1` and `$0=RS $0` i.e `$0` or simply `whole record` becomes `"\n"$0` (basically adding newline at the beginning of record).  `a!=$1` will always satisfy when there is a different first field (`$1`) than the previous line's `$1` and is thus a criteria to segregate our records based on first field.

`a==$1`: If it matches then it probably means you are iterating over a record belonging to the previous record set. In this case substitute first occurrence of `$1:` (Note the `:` ) for eg. `apple:` with `;`.  `$1":"` could also be written as `$1FS` where `FS is :`

If you have millions of line in your file then this approach would be fastest because it doesn't involve any pre-processing and also we are not using any other data structure say array for storing your keys or records.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation.

Comment: @MichaelD: Welcome Michael.

Answer (score 3):

@RahulVerma's `awk` solution is simple and awesome! However, I've been looking for a `sed` solution. I wondered if `sed` is capable to solve this sort of problem. Finally, I've found my own solution! The core idea is **treat the hold space as a variable, put what we want to search in the hold space, and search it in the current input line**. I want to give credit to @chaos, because the core idea is from his answer [how-to-search-for-the-word-stored-in-the-hold-space-with-sed#239049](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239035/how-to-search-for-the-word-stored-in-the-hold-space-with-sed#239049).

---

Using **sed** one liner

```
sed -E '1{:OK; h; $b; d}; x; G; s/^([^:]+)(.*)\n\1:(.*)/\1\2;\3/; tOK; s/\n.*//' file
```

or

```
sed -E 'x; G; s/^([^:]+)(.*)\n\1:(.*)/\1\2;\3/; tOK; 1d; s/\n.*//; b; :OK; h; $!d' file
```

**Output:**

```
apple:A fruit;Type of: pie
banana:tropical fruit
cherry:small burgundy fruit;1 for me to eat;bright red
```

---

**Explanation: (the 2nd `sed`)**

- `x` exchange the hold space and the pattern space

  - The hold space would become the current input line.
  - The pattern space would become the content generated by `s///` in the last cycle (see below), or the last input line if `s///` fails to replace anything. It is empty for the very beginning, i.e., when the current input line is the line 1.
- `G` append the hold space (the current input line) to the pattern space (the content generated in the last cycle). Thus, the pattern space would be two lines (The hold space is not changed). For example,

  - If the current input line is line 1, the pattern space would be

    ```sh
                                 # the empty hold space
    apple:A fruit                # the current input line
    ```
  - If it is line 2, the pattern space would be

    ```sh
    apple:A fruit                # the last input line, because `s///` fails to replace anything in the last cycle
    apple:Type of: pie           # the current input line
    ```
  - If it is line 3, the pattern space would be

    ```sh
    apple:A fruit;Type of: pie   # the resulting content generated by `s///` in the last cycle
    banana:tropical fruit        # the current input line
    ```
- `s///` use the first field `^([^:]+)` (`:` is the field separator) in the first line of the pattern space to search the second line. The part of `\n\1:` indicates how it works. If it is found in the second line, concatenate the first line `\1\2'`, a `;`, and the 2+ fields of the second line `\3`. Thus, the result is `\1\2;\3`.
- `tOK` if the `s///` is successful (`s` has replaced something) jump to the label `OK`, otherwise continue

  - In case of success

    - `:OK` specify the location of the label `OK`
    - `h` put the pattern space which is `\1\2;\3`, generated by `s///`, to the hold space. (The first line of the pattern space in the next cycle is made up of this very content)
    - `$!d` delete it, don't print it, if hasn't reached the last line
  - In case of failure, (`s///` hasn't changed anything, the pattern space still has two lines)

    - `1d` delete the pattern space, don't print it, if the current input line is the line 1. At this moment, there is nothing ready to output. Without this, an empty line would be printed.
    - `s/\n.*//` delete the second line of the pattern space, which is the current input line.
    - `b` jump without a label, means end the `sed` script, and the remaining content in the pattern space would be printed out before starting the next cycle.

      - This is the very place where we finish combining the lines starting with the "current" same field and print out the combined line.
      - The hold space is still holding the the current input line for this cycle, and is going to be "the last input line" for the next cycle (see above). What it holds will trigger a brand new combining of the lines starting with a new same field.

---

In the second `sed` command line, the `1d;` is not very necessary, however, the output has a subtle difference without it -- an innocuous empty line would be printed on the top, like below,

```
apple:A fruit;Type of: pie
banana:tropical fruit
cherry:small burgundy fruit;1 for me to eat;bright red
```

---

**Thoughts at the end**

The time I spent to figuring out the `sed` solution and the final look of the `sed` solution, both indicates that `awk` is better and easier for problems as complicated as this. `sed` is not good at searching/replacing a file according to the file itself. Like, searching/replacing constant text, it is easy, but what to search/replace is from the file itself, which means it might vary from line to line. For this kind, `sed` is not as good as `awk` -- the superior that has the full programming facilities, like variable, function, if-else, for/while/do. (See further in [what is the difference between sed and awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632113/what-is-the-difference-between-sed-and-awk))

Comment: Thanks for making and sharing this, including your breakdown.

Answer (score 2):

Discover **awk** language:

```
awk -F':' '{ v=substr($0, index($0,":")+1); a[$1]=($1 in a? a[$1]";" : "")v }
           END{ for(i in a) print i,a[i] }' OFS=':' infile.txt
```

The output:

```
apple:A fruit;Type of: pie
banana:tropical fruit
cherry:small burgundy fruit;1 for me to eat;bright red
```

Comment: Thanks @RomanPerekhrest, that works. Better than some other awk solutions I've tried in the past which would break on complex lines. That said, I'd still love a shorter command with a simpler syntax, but I am pleased to have a one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

```
for F in `cut -f1 -d ':' infile.txt | sort | uniq`; do echo "$F:$(grep $F infile.txt | cut -f2- -d ':' | paste -s -d ';' - )"; done
```

Not sure it qualifies as 'elegant', but it works, though I'm sure not quickly for millions of lines - as the number of `grep` calls increases it would slow significantly.  What % of the matching fields do you expect to be unique?

Comment: Thanks for the unix string. I expect around 1-5 repeats of a key/matching-field, so in a million lines, there might be 300k keys.

Comment: Ah, 300k grep calls would be unreasonable.  Thanks for the feedback

Comment: However, this is still a good example of unix philosophy.

Answer (score 2):

I think this one do the job

```
 awk -F':' '$1!=a{if(b);print b;b=""}a=$1{$1="";if(!b)b=a;b=b$0}END{print b}' infile
```

Comment: Can you explain it?

Answer (score 2):

As an exercise - or even for smallish datasets - the same in just native `bash` interpreter commands:

```
declare -A fruit=()
while IFS=: read k v; do fruit[$k]="${fruit[$k]:+${fruit[$k]};}$v"; done < test.in
for k in "${!fruit[@]}"; do echo "$k:${fruit[$k]}"; done
```

Output:

```
apple:A fruit;Type of: pie
banana:tropical fruit
cherry:small burgundy fruit;1 for me to eat;bright red
```

Any required sorting order might need to be explicitly enforced in more complex datasets.